# Add SocksPort using Tor Controller?

Tags: configuration, protocol

Can I add additional SOCKSPORT entries using Tor Controller?  I looked through control-spec.txt and could only find examples of reading the current SOCKSPORT using GETCONF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave it a shot, and it appears to work:

```
setconf SOCKSPORT=23999 SOCKSPORT=24999
250 OK
getconf SOCKSPORT
250-SocksPort=23999
250 SocksPort=24999
GETINFO net/listeners/socks
250-net/listeners/socks="127.0.0.1:23999" "127.0.0.1:24999"
```